# How to create a sql table if table does not exsists using php?

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create a table if the table is not present in the database - using PHP.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(!$conn)
    {
            die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
            exit;
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname);
    if(!$db_selected)
    {
           $db_selected = " CREATE DATABASE $dbname ";
    }
    $usertb1 = mysql_query("select 1 from $usertb LIMIT 1");
    if( $usertb1 !== FALSE )
    {
           $sql = "CREATE TABLE $usertb( uid INT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL,name VARCHAR(40),email varchar(40) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)";
    }
    $typetb1 = mysql_query("select 1 from $typetb LIMIT 1");
    if( $typetb1 !== FALSE)
    {
           $sql1 = "CREATE TABLE $typetb( uid INT(20) NOT NULL, type ENUM('QUERYHOMEWEB','QUERYHOMEAPP','ANSWERCART') NOT NULL ,unsubscribe TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,bounce TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,complaint TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (uid,type), FOREIGN KEY(uid) WHERE promo_user(uid))";
    }
```

please tell me what wrong with this code.

Comment: You don't execute those sql queries that create database or table

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the sql for `CREATE TABLE` to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

```
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(!$conn)
    {
            die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
            exit;
    }
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbname);
    if(!$db_selected)
    {
           $db_selected = " CREATE DATABASE $dbname ";
    }
    $usertb1 = mysql_query("select 1 from $usertb LIMIT 1");
    if( $usertb1 !== FALSE )
    {
           $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $usertb( uid INT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE KEY NOT NULL,name VARCHAR(40),email varchar(40) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)";
    }
    $typetb1 = mysql_query("select 1 from $typetb LIMIT 1");
    if( $typetb1 !== FALSE)
    {
           $sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $typetb( uid INT(20) NOT NULL, type ENUM('QUERYHOMEWEB','QUERYHOMEAPP','ANSWERCART') NOT NULL ,unsubscribe TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,bounce TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,complaint TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (uid,type), FOREIGN KEY(uid) WHERE promo_user(uid))";
    }
```